# One word for talking with a raised voice (but not shouting)

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means talking with a raised voice, but still a few decibels short of shouting. Imagine for example the beginning of an argument:

> "I sold our cow for some beans."
>
> "You did *what*?" ____ed Jack's mother.
>
> "*Magic* beans."
>
> "You *imbecile!*" she shouted.

You get the idea. *Say* and *tell* seem a bit too weak, whereas *shout*, *scream*, *cry* and the like are a bit too loud.

Perhaps another way to describe it is the sort of voice you use when you'd like to shout, but you're not sure if it's socially appropriate for you to do so (for the moment).

I've considered "call out" but it doesn't quite seem like it fits.

Comment: Try "*balked*" (unrelated to volume, but meets the context).

Comment: ". . . queried Jack's mother incredulously."

Comment: @DanBron Using a context-specific word is definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

["Exclaim"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exclaim)

"You did what?!" exclaimed Jack's Mother.

Note also the addition of the exclamation mark.

Comment: +1, Exclaim and @bib's -snap, seems to be in tune with OP's context.

Comment: +1, Good point about the exclamation point. You could just use 'said' and get across the volume with the punctuation.

Comment: This is the best choice; most of the other suggestions here have other connotations.  See http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exclaim?s=t  Since the utterance in question is a question, "demand" might also be suitable.

Comment: "Exclaim" is the best fit, I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Perhaps *[barked](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bark)*

> To speak sharply; snap: "a spot where you can just drop in ... without anyone's barking at you for failing to plan ahead" (Andy Birsh).

*American Heritage*

And as suggested in the prior offering, *[snap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/snap)*

> Say something quickly and irritably to someone:
>
> [NO OBJECT]: *McIllvanney snapped at her*
>
> [WITH DIRECT SPEECH]: *“I really don’t much care,” she snapped*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: `barked` in that context will makes it sound that Jack's Mother is a b*tch (female dog).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Acting like a dog is independent of gender.

Comment: I know, I know. I'm just saying. It really isn't the best word, unless you are saying bad things about Jack's Mother.

Answer (score 4):

snap

"You did what?"snapped Jack's mother. (No pun intended with respect to the beans).

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with adverbs--*said loudly*, *told him loudly*, etc. There's also *say/tell in a raised voice.*

As for single words, here are a few (definitions from Merriam-Webster):

- **[Holler](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holler)**: to call out loudly
- **[Bellow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bellow)**: to shout in a deep voice
- **[Roar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roar)**: to sing or shout with full force

In another vein, *hiss* has the connotation of being angry, but deliberately keeping your voice low. "'You did *what*?' hissed Jack's mother."

Comment: I would consider 'holler', 'bellow', and 'roar' to all be *at least* as loud as 'shout'.

Answer (score 3):

*Exclaim* is good, but also tends to imply an emotional response in addition to the added volume.

[Vociferate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vociferate) is the best single word I can think of that refers to increased volume, with or without the "emotional baggage".

Comment: 'Vociferate' may be technically correct, but I would be surprised by anyway even knowing the word, much less using it.

Comment: @DCShannon agreed, but then that depends on the context, too. All of the answers here carry other connotations, such as surprise or anger, so I'll still insist that it's the best single word that meets Andrey's request. I just wish I could remember the what Safire wrote about using a word when you weren't sure the audience would understand it...basically it was to aim slightly over their heads, to give them the benefit of the doubt and get them to pull out their dictionary once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

*[Shriek](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shriek)*:

> "You did what?" shrieked Jack's mother.

*[Yelp](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yelp)*:

> "You did what?" yelped Jack's mother.

Comment: 'Yelp' has the connotation of fear or surprise rather than anger, so I don't think that works. Shriek may work, depending on the tenor of the voice involved.

Answer (score 1):

Alas, the verb ejaculated is an excellent fit, but it perhaps can no longer be used in this context since many people only would read it as a sexual reference.

Webster's: to say (something) suddenly and forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

How about [ejaculated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ejaculate):

> to utter suddenly and briefly; exclaim.

In context:

> You did what?" ejaculated Jack's mother.

Of course, ahem, context is very important when using this word.

Answer (score -3):

["project (one's voice)"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exclaim)

> to use one's voice forcefully enough to be heard at a distance, as in a theater.

It communicates the loudness of the words without the connotation of being argumentative or losing control.

Comment: But it would sound strange if it were used to describe people talking without much distance between them.

Comment: Also, *project* isn't usually used with quoted speech. The equivalent (or near enough) could be *call*.